# How to disable a region?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-regions

I don't want letting people to use AWS services in region they should not use.
Can I disable regions entirely for an Organization?

I see here "You cannot disable a Region that is enabled by default." here:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande-manage.html

is there another way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't disable the region per se, but you can prevent users from performing actions in whatever required region by using a SCP that denies all actions when the context key `aws:RequestedRegion` matches said region.

For more information: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_condition-keys.html